# tab is not being loaded - bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page where locations are shown. and there i have two tabs, one for googmaps and one for weather.

for example this location http://www.places4two.de/location/date-in-mozart-stuben/45/

but if you see, if you switch to weather tab, the tab is not loaded fully. if i make the weather tab first active, then googlemaps tab is not loaded fully.

what am i doing wrong here?

this is the code:

```
  $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).tab('show');
  });
```

html

```
<div style="padding-left: 75px">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#lage">Lage</a></li>
    <li><a href="#wetter">Wetter</a></li>
  </ul>
</div> 
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="lage">
     <div id="map-canvas" style="max-width: 1100px; height: 350px"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="wetter">
     <div id="basicMap" style="max-width: 1100px; height: 350px"> </div>    
  </div>                  
</div>
```

thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $('a[href="#lage"]').on('shown', function(e) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });

    $('#myTab a[href="#lage"]').on('shown', function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        map.setCenter(latlng);
    });
```

You need to resize the map when calling it on tab.

Comment: thanks, but gmaps is working fine without resizing. i need to fix the weather plugin OpenLayers

Answer (score 0):

i solved this in another way.

```
$(function(){
$('#wetter').hide();
 $('#wetteron').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#lage').hide();
        $('#wetter').show();
        $('#lageon').parent('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');                                
     });
     $('#lageon').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#wetter').hide();
        $('#lage').show();
        $('#wetteron').parent('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
     });
});
```

added html

```
<li class="active"><a href="#lage" id="lageon">Lage</a></li>
<li><a href="#wetter" id="wetteron">Wetter</a></li>
```